# Symfony2 & FOS_RestBundle: How can I make the body listener always decode json content despite the Content-Type of the Request?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm building a webservice and I intend to provide only a json interface.

To that end I want to make it as easy as possible for users to interact with my API. In an ideal world consumers send requests with a Content-Type header of 'application/json', however I'd like my API to accept a json encoded request irrespective of the Content-Type Header.

I'm using Symfony2 and FOS_RESTBundle and have set up a body listener and format listener together with a route to my controller that should force the format to be application json.

If I send a request with a Content-Type of 'application/json' the body is correctly decoded. 
Any other Content-Type header results is a null value for $data in the example below. $type is always json (due to the _format in the route).

Where am I going wrong?

```
// config.yaml 
fos_rest:
view:
    view_response_listener: false
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: php
    formats:
        text: false
        xml: false
        html: false
        json: true
format_listener:
    default_priorities: ['application/json']
    fallback_format: json
    prefer_extension: true
body_listener:
    decoders:
        json: fos_rest.decoder.json
```

And -

```
// Routing.yaml

_api_contact_request_create:
  pattern: /api/merchant/{merchantId}/customer-contact-request
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeApiBundle:CustomerContact:Create, _format: json}
  type: rest
  requirements: 
     _method: POST
```

Finally -

```
    // Extract from Controller
    public function CreateAction($merchantId) {

        $data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('data');

        $type = $this->getRequest()->getRequestFormat();

        var_dump($type, $data);die;
```

Comment: You could create a listener on the `kernel.request`, and add yourself the Content-Type: application/json ... only if you detected a json body

Comment: Just had a quick look and I think Adrien's right, the BodyListener takes Content-Type over the request format, so you'll need to fudge a header, or write your own DecoderProviderInterface that says yes to ->supports($whatever) and override the default.